# Convert floating point raster array to integer raster using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, integer

I was searching a lot for everything related to this topic. Could someone give me an idea, a suggestion how could I convert the cell values of a float raster to integer in Python environment using GDAL?

I have tried this:

```
int(round(myarray))
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? Why is this not working? What errors, if any, are you getting? What are you expecting and what is it doing? Please paste more of your code. int(myarray) should work. If you use round, you should specify the rounding precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is for scalars. For an array, I would recommend numpy:

```py
import numpy
numpy.asarray(myarray, dtype=int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, the raster cell values are now integer values without decimals but if I open the raster in QGIS it says that the data type is Float32.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. Can you open a new question with the code for how you are reading/writing the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
def saveRaster(dataset,datasetPath,cols,rows,projection):
rasterSet = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(datasetPath, cols, rows,1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
rasterSet.SetProjection(projection)
rasterSet.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
rasterSet.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(dataset)
rasterSet.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-999)
rasterSet = None
```

And after the creation of the raster:

```
saveRaster(RBR_MultiplyBy1000_Int,path_RBR_MultiplyBy1000_Int,cols,rows,projection)
```

Maybe because is set as `gdal.GDT_Float32` ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my question: Yes, this was the issue.

```
def saveRaster_Int(dataset,datasetPath,cols,rows,projection):
rasterSet = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(datasetPath, cols, rows,1,gdal.GDT_Int16)
rasterSet.SetProjection(projection)
rasterSet.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
rasterSet.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(dataset)
rasterSet.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-999)
rasterSet = None

saveRaster_Int(RBR_MultiplyBy1000_Int,path_RBR_MultiplyBy1000_Int,cols,rows,projection)
```